# How to use Json.Net to deserialize json that starts with a property name of a number?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize some JSON data from an API endpoint, and the data is enclosed in a `{8: myData}`. I cannot figure out how to deserialize it with the first property being named a number.

Example JSON:

```
{
8: 
  [
    data, 
    data2, 
    data3, 
    data4
  ]
}
```

My deserializer line fails since the first property name of the JSON data is an `8`:

```
IEnumerable<ApiCombatOverallRank> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ApiCombatOverallRank>>(resultsString);
```

I can create an anonymous type like this:

```
var anonType = new { data = new List<ApiCombatOverallRank>() };
IEnumerable<ApiCombatOverallRank> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(resultsString, anonType).data;
```

However, it will not deserialize as the property name in the JSON is `8` not `data`. C# will not allow me to create an anonymous object like:

```
var anonType = new { 8 = new List<ApiCombatOverallRank>() };
```

Similarly, I am unable to add an annotation to an anonomyous object like:

```
var anonType = new {[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "8")] data = new List<ApiCombatOverallRank>() };
```

How can I deserialize this JSON and get past the first JSON object property of `8`?

Comment: as far as I can see from JSON validation, this isn't valid json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is parsebar as (after i  made strings from your "data's" ):

```
var result = JsonConvert
     .DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<string>>>(resultsString);
```

so i think, your real json you could parse as :

```
var result = JsonConvert
     .DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<ApiCombatOverallRank>>>(resultsString);
```

and your first kson object your could access as:

```
result[8].First();
```